# the dimension of the zero coomology space of normal bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose that $S$ is a surface of general type canonically embedded by the canonical divisor in the space $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n$. Take the curve $C=H\cap S$ with $H$ the divisor of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$. We can define the normal bundle $N_{C/S}$. How can i compute the dimension of the space $H^0(C,N_{C/S})$.
i don't know if it is usefull but, using the adjunction formula, we get that $N_{C/S}\equiv H_{|C}$.

Comment: I see a reltion for the normal bundle. $C=S \cap H$  is a divisor on $S$. So in my situation can i say that $N_{C/S}$ is equal to ${O}_{C}(C)$?

Comment: I've seen that this relation holds: $N_{C/S}=N_{H/ \mathbb{P}^n}$. So is it possible to easly compute $h^0(C,N_{H/ \mathbb{P}^n})$? for example using the riemann roch theorem?

Answer (score 1):

you need $C^2$ this number is the degree of S in $\mathbb{P}^n$. It depends on the embedding. 
Then applying adjunction formula(for both S and C in  $\mathbb{P}^n$) and Riemann-Roch.

Comment: for example suppose that $S$ is the complete intersection of four quadric in $\mathbb{P}^6$. This is a canonical embedded surface via the canonical map. So $C^2$ is equal to $16$. Can you show me how to compute $h^0(C,N_{H/ \mathbb{P}^6})$ in this example?

Comment: By adjunction formula, I can get $K_S=16H^5 $, and $K_C=32H^6$, $N_{C|S}=16H^6$, where $H$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^6$. By R-R, can have $g(C)=17$.   $h^0(0)=1, h^0(32)=17$, $h^0(31)-h^0(1)=31-17+1=15$, $h^0(30)-h^0(2)=30-17+1=14$, ...$h^0(18)-h^0(14)=2$, $h^0(17)-h^0(15)=1$, so I think $h^0$ goes up by 1, as degree goes up by 2, then I guess $h^0(C,N_{C|S})=h^0(16)=8$.  I'm not totally sure though. ~

Comment: Can you explain your notation $h^0(32)$ for example? why do you use a number instead of a divisor?

Comment: using adjunction formula i get $K_S=O_S(H)$. is this equal to $16H$?

Comment: you write $K_C=32H$ but $H$ is not a divisor on $C$ as $K_C$?

Comment: $H^6$ is a point. so $32H^6$ is divisor of C consists of 32 points on C.

Comment: the number 6, on the top of $H$ means that we are in $\mathbb{P}^6$?

Comment: H is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^6$, $H^6$ means the intersection of six hyperplanes, so it is 0-dim, i.e. a point. Or you can think $H$ as a generator of Chow ring